# How can we write the regular expression in Perl with back referencing

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to back referencing with matched string in one liner code. below is the sample record. Please some one help on this.Thanks in advance.

sample Record:

> 127.0.0.11 [28/Aug/2017:12:23:21 ]

```
perl -pe 's/^(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)( *$)/\1__/' samplefile.txt
```

Here i want the output as :

```
127.0.0.11__
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it expects an IP address, followed by optional spaces, followed by the end of the line. But your actual data contains other other text (`[28/Aug/2017:12:23:21 ]`).

You can do this instead:

```
perl -pe 's/^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*/$1__/' samplefile.txt
```

`.*` matches any remaining text on the line.

Also, you don't want a backreference here: A backreference looks like `\1` and is part of regex syntax. But the right-hand side of a substitution is not a regex, it's a double-quotish string. And after a successful regex match you use the capture variables `$1`, `$2`, ... to refer to matched substrings.

Comment: Could you please give the output? Here i am getting only underscores at my console.

Comment: Well, look at output of my answer. ;-)

Comment: @learner Output is `127.0.0.11__` (as described in your question). How are you running this?

Comment: No, i have different ip-addresses. I used double quote, that's why i am not getting the proper output. like perl -pe "///" < file. If i used single quote it is working fine to me. But i didn't understand the difference between single and double quote here.

Comment: @learner That's a shell thing. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes. Basically, double quotes interpolate shell variables, so you got the value of the shell variable `$1` (which was empty), resulting in perl receiving `s/^(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+).*/__/` as input.

Comment: @melpomene, Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Do not forget to escape dots in the pattern if they are meant to match literal dots in the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat samplefile.txt
127.0.0.11 [28/Aug/2017:12:23:21 ]
127.0.0.11 [28/Aug/2017:12:23:22 ]
127.0.0.11 [28/Aug/2017:12:23:23 ]
127.0.0.11 [28/Aug/2017:12:23:24 ]
```

The regex to use:

```
^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)            # matching ip-address
.*                               # 0 or more characters
```

Use capture variable $1 to copy the ip-address, followed by '__':

```
$ perl -pe 's/^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*/$1__/' samplefile.txt
127.0.0.11__
127.0.0.11__
127.0.0.11__
127.0.0.11__
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation of your code and why it solves the issue? *Code only* answers are often not that helpful.

Comment: Fair enough. Done.

Comment: Or `s/^\d+(?:\.\d+){3}\K.*/__/a`

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. You missed to put `.` before `*` in second character set.

you can try either of the below codes.

```
perl -pe 's/^(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)(.*$)/\1__/' text.txt
```

or

```
perl -pe 's/^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(\s)(.*)/\1__/' text.txt
```

both will give you the desired result.

content of text.txt

```
127.0.0.11 [28/Aug/2017:12:23:21 ]
127.0.0.112 [28/Aug/2017:12:23:21 ]
127.0.0.13 [28/Aug/2017:12:23:21 ]
127.0.0.4 [28/Aug/2017:12:23:21 ]
```

output

```
127.0.0.11__
127.0.0.112__
127.0.0.13__
127.0.0.4__
```